# Can't evaluate null number in formula field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I'm trying to make a Date Formula field that display the next month in my record.

I got the object EntryLine__c where I display the year and month of my entry line.

Here is my formula :

```
IF(ISNULL(Year__c) || ISNULL(Month__c),
DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),1,1),
IF(Month__c = 12, DATE(Year__c + 1, 1, 1),
DATE(Year__c, Month__c+1, 1)))
```

Year__c and Month__c are Numbers field. I'm testing if they are null because I don't want to have a null value in my formula. I'm using it in a time trigger and if it's null it will abort my Process Builder.

I tried with ISBLANK and ISNULL functions but it doesn't work. They're still evaluated to False even if my fields are empty. So I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options

1) Make sure that you have configured the formula correctly and that in the section `Blank Field Handling`, you have selected `Treat blank fields as blanks` (it defaults to `Treat blank fields as zeroes`, which basically means that when a null / blank is found, a zero is assumed instead)

2) Check for zero in your formula (option 1 is preferred)

Comment: Thx, I didn't know how exactly the `Blank Field Handling` work. I won't make the same mistake !